# Sinon.stub not stubbing private method

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

In the following module I have a private method which creates a temporary directory. I am writing the tests for this module, `resize`, and want to stub its private method `createTmpFile` and return a fake directory. I am using `sinon` to do this, but the original method is still being called.

I've tried requiring the private method with `var _private = require('../lib/modules/resizer')._private;` and then stubbing it in my test suit with `tmpStub = sinon.stub(_private, 'createTmpFile', function () { return "/temporary/"});`

This throws no errors, but still stop the function from being called.

How can I replace the private method with the stub?

`resize`

```
'use strict';

// dependencies
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
var tmp = require('tmp');
var async = require('async');

var resizer = {};

resizer.resize = function (path, sizesObj, callback) {
    console.log(path);

    var directory = createTmpFile();

    var imgType = path.split(".").pop();

    async.each(sizesObj, function (sizesObj, mapNext) {
        gm(path)
            .resize(sizesObj.width, sizesObj.height)
            .write(directory + sizesObj.name + "." + imgType, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    mapNext(err);
                }
                mapNext();
            });
    }, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(directory);
        }
    });
};

// This function creates a temporary directory to which we will save our files.
var createTmpFile = function () {

    var tmpDir = tmp.dirSync(); //object
    var tmpDirName = tmpDir.name + "/"; //path to directory
    return tmpDirName;
};

module.exports = resizer;

if ( process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    module.exports._private = {
        createTmpFile: createTmpFile
    }
};
```

`test`

```
   describe("resizer when data is path", function () {
        var testedModule, dir, sizesObj, tmpStub, writeStub250, writeStub500, writeStub650, writeStub750, callbackSpy, resizeStub, gmSubClassStub;
        var _private = require('../lib/modules/resizer')._private;
        console.log(_private.createTmpFile);

        before(function () {

            dir = "/tmp/rstest.png";

            sizesObj = [
                {name: "thumb", width: 250, height: 250},
                {name: "small", width: 500, height: 500},
                {name: "medium", width: 650, height: 650},
                {name: "large", width: 750, height: 750}
            ];


            writeStub250 = sinon.stub();
            writeStub500 = sinon.stub();
            writeStub650 = sinon.stub();
            writeStub750 = sinon.stub();

            resizeStub = sinon.stub();

            tmpStub = sinon.stub(_private, 'createTmpFile', function () { return "/temporary/"});

            gmSubClassStub = sinon.stub();

            callbackSpy = sinon.spy();

            testedModule = proxyquire('../lib/modules/resizer', {
                'gm': {subClass: sinon.stub().returns(gmSubClassStub)}
            });

        });

        after(function () {
            _private.createTmpFile.restore();
        });

        it("resize image and write to path", function () {

            resizeStub.withArgs(250, 250).returns({write:writeStub250});
            resizeStub.withArgs(500, 500).returns({write:writeStub500});
            resizeStub.withArgs(650, 650).returns({write:writeStub650});
            resizeStub.withArgs(750, 750).returns({write:writeStub750});

            // Stub is used when you just want to simulate a returned value
            gmSubClassStub.withArgs(dir).returns({resize:resizeStub});

            // Act - this calls the tested method
            testedModule.resize(dir, sizesObj, function (err) {
                callbackSpy.apply(null, arguments);
            });

            expect(writeStub250).has.been.called.and.calledWith("/temporary/thumb.png");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're stubbing `_private.createTmpFile`, which holds a *reference* to your private function. You're replacing the reference with the stub, but that's not the same as stubbing the original function.

Unless you actually use `exports._private.createTmpFile` (which is not something you want because `exports._private` only exists in the `test` environment) in your resize function, you won't be using the stub but the actual function (because `createTmpFile` still points to the original function).

Not sure if there's a clean way to solve this, to be honest.

Comment: Is there a way to get around not having my tests spin-up temporary directories every time they are run?

Comment: @hyprstack you could perhaps use `mockery` or `proxyquire` to mock `tmp.dirSync()` (or use the [`unsafeCleanup`](https://github.com/raszi/node-tmp#asynchronous-directory-creation) option so it'll remove the temporary directories for you)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had tried using `proxyquire` to mock `tmp.dirSync()` at first, but incorrectly. However I tried again and changed what I was doing and came to a solution. I now have my tests passing! I have added my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @robertklep comments, I decided to tackle the issue with `proxyquire` once again and came to the following solution which passes my tests.

I have changed the set-up by adding `tmp.dirSync` to `proxyquire` and force it to return the fake directory. I also removed the stub for the temporary directory.

```
describe("resizer when data is path", function () {
    var testedModule, dir, sizesObj, writeStub250, writeStub500, writeStub650, writeStub750, callbackSpy, resizeStub, gmSubClassStub;

    before(function () {

        dir = "/tmp/rstest.png";

        sizesObj = [
            {name: "thumb", width: 250, height: 250},
            {name: "small", width: 500, height: 500},
            {name: "medium", width: 650, height: 650},
            {name: "large", width: 750, height: 750}
        ];


        writeStub250 = sinon.stub();
        writeStub500 = sinon.stub();
        writeStub650 = sinon.stub();
        writeStub750 = sinon.stub();

        resizeStub = sinon.stub();

        gmSubClassStub = sinon.stub();

        callbackSpy = sinon.spy();

        testedModule = proxyquire('../lib/modules/resizer', {
            'gm': {subClass: sinon.stub().returns(gmSubClassStub)},
            'tmp': {
                'dirSync': function () {
                    return {
                        name: "/temporary"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

    it("resize image and write to path", function () {

        resizeStub.withArgs(250, 250).returns({write:writeStub250});
        resizeStub.withArgs(500, 500).returns({write:writeStub500});
        resizeStub.withArgs(650, 650).returns({write:writeStub650});
        resizeStub.withArgs(750, 750).returns({write:writeStub750});

        // Stub is used when you just want to simulate a returned value
        gmSubClassStub.withArgs(dir).returns({resize:resizeStub});

        // Act - this calls the tested method
        testedModule.resize(dir, sizesObj, function (err) {
            callbackSpy.apply(null, arguments);
        });

        expect(writeStub250).has.been.called.and.calledWith("/temporary/thumb.png");
        expect(writeStub500).has.been.called.and.calledWith("/temporary/small.png");
        expect(writeStub650).has.been.called.and.calledWith("/temporary/medium.png");
        expect(writeStub750).has.been.called.and.calledWith("/temporary/large.png");

    });

    it("calls callbackSpy", function () {

        writeStub250.callsArgWith(1, null);
        writeStub500.callsArgWith(1, null);
        writeStub650.callsArgWith(1, null);
        writeStub750.callsArgWith(1, null);

        resizeStub.withArgs(250, 250).returns({write:writeStub250});
        resizeStub.withArgs(500, 500).returns({write:writeStub500});
        resizeStub.withArgs(650, 650).returns({write:writeStub650});
        resizeStub.withArgs(750, 750).returns({write:writeStub750});

        // Stub is used when you just want to simulate a returned value
        gmSubClassStub.withArgs(dir).returns({resize:resizeStub});

        // Act - this calls the tested method
        testedModule.resize(dir, sizesObj, function (err) {
            callbackSpy.apply(null, arguments);
        });

        expect(callbackSpy).has.been.called.and.calledWith('/temporary/');
    });
});
```